# How to remove the 'Format/Category' Permalink in URL?

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

In the settings on my WordPress website, I need Post Permalink looks like "`zzzz.com/sample-post/`". My website however uses custom posts so I downloaded the plugin 'Remove slug from custom post type' but all posts are still appearing in the format "`zzzz.com/format/category/sample-post/`". I want the '`format/category`' part removed from the URL. Just wondering if there is another similar plugin to the above that would remove this or if there is some code I need to manually enter?

Answer (score 1):

First Disable your plugin you installed !!

**Set Custom Structure:** `/%postname%/`

**Set Category base:** `. (dot not /)`

Try this before use change `your_post_type` to your post type

```
function firefog_remove_cpt_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

    if ( ! in_array( $post->post_type, array( 'your_post_type' ) ) || 'publish' != $post->post_status )
        return $post_link;

    $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );

    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'firefog_remove_cpt_slug', 10, 3 );

function firefog_parse_request_tricksy( $query ) {

    // Only noop the main query
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    // Only noop our very specific rewrite rule match
    if ( 2 != count( $query->query )
        || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) )
        return;

    // 'name' will be set if post permalinks are just post_name, otherwise the page rule will match
    if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'your_post_type', 'page' ) );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'firefog_parse_request_tricksy' );
```

Answer (score 0):

In wp-admin go to the following menu: `Settings` -> `Permalinks`. You're now on Permalinks page, select `Post name` option. You can also play around with the `Custom Structure` option.

Comment: That was the first thing I did but no matter what I enter, the custom posts are still appearing in the format "zzzz.com/format/category/sample-post/" but I want them to appear like this: "zzzz.com/sample-post/"